# How can I change the color of a single ggplot layer?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, spatial

I need to change the white part of this ggplot to `color = 'red', fill='red', alpha=0.1` without changing the colors of the other 2 layers in the plot. I want to see the base layer under the white area. I have tried several variations of `aes(color = 'red', fill='red', alpha=0.1)` inside and outside of the `geom_sf()`. I have also moved `new_scale_color()` to different places in the code. How can this be accomplished?

[image: ggplot of 3 rasters]

```
#####################################################
#create ggplot object combing NAIP, treat, and home ranges
HR_ani <- NAIPgg + geom_sf(data=treatment, aes(color = 'red', fill='red', alpha=0.1))  + new_scale_color() +
  geom_sf(data = (deer1),aes(color = Id, fill = Id, alpha = Id)) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.8, 0.4)) + #manually set the alpha values for each indiv
  scale_color_manual(values = viridis(3)[1:10]) + #manually set the colours for each individual
  scale_fill_manual(values = viridis(2)[1:10]) + #manually set the colours for each individual
  theme(legend.position="none", panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) + 
  transition_states(YearMonth, wrap=T, transition_length = 0, state_length = .5) + labs(title = "YearMonth: {closest_state}", size=50)
```

Comment: Instead of making `Tr` a separate plot you could try to add it via `+ geom_sf(data = treatment, .....)`

Comment: @stefan I have tried that, but I get ```Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()```.

Comment: Have you used `data = ...`, i.e. doing `+ geom_sf(treatment, ...)` will result in the error you mentioned.

Comment: Adding ```geom_sf(data=treatment)``` worked! However, when I try to incorporate the colors I want for the treatment area, I get ```Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale```.

Comment: Hm. I don't see any reason for this error in your code ... but in general this error indicates that you mapped a discrete variable on the color aes (which will add a discrete color scale to the ggplot) and then mapped a continuous variable on the color scale.

Comment: ... if you want both a continuous and a discrete color scale or multiple scales then have a look at the `ggnewscale` package.

Comment: Thanks @ Stefan. I appreciate all of your help. Things are coming together. I have edited the post explaining new issues.

Comment: Now the issue gets clearer. In your updated code `aes(color = "red", ...)` will add a discrete scale. If `Id` is a continuous then you get an error. If you just want to set the color and fill of your first layer to "red" then move it outside of aes(). Also in this case there no need for `new_scale_color` (so remove it).

Comment: That fixed everything. Thank You!